# PHP for maximum items in for dosent show

Tags: php, for-loop

I wrote a code that calculate for from X to Y for example: for from 1 to 10

My problem that is $episodes = 10; but its showing only from 1 to 9 and not to 10.

```html
<?php 
$episodes = 10;
for($i=1; $i<$episodes; $i++){ // Its showing till 9 and its supposed to be till 10
?>
      <li data-season="<?= $value['season']; ?>" data-episode="<?= $i; ?>" class="active"> // 
  <a class="text-center" href=""><?= $i; ?></a>
  <i class="fa fa-lg fa-eye pointer" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `for($i=1; $i<=$episodes; $i++)`

Comment: `$i<=$episodes` or `$i=0;`

Comment: You told `for loop` to run till `$i<$episodes` starting from `1` and it obeyed.

Comment: Indexes in most programming languages start from 0. If you wanna be a programmer learn to count from 0 not from 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You for loop condition is wrong you have to write
Try this.

```
$episodes = 11;
for($i=1; $i<$episodes; $i++)
```

or

```
$episodes = 10
for($i=1; $i<=$episodes; $i++)
```